# c# Graphics and GraphicsPath Alignment

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm attempting to draw some centered text inside of a custom panel control. I'm able to create the text path using `GraphicsPath.AddString` and draw the text using `Graphics.FillPath`. Here's the code I'm using (it resides inside the custom panel control).

```
public void ApplyCenteredTextMessage(string message, FontStyle fontStyle)
    {
        using (Font messageFont = new Font("Arial", 36, fontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Point))
        {
            using (StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat())
            {
                stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                using (Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics())
                {
                    using (Font adjustedMessageFont = GetAdjustedFont(graphics, message, messageFont, this.Bounds, 160, 10))
                    {
                        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
                        {
                            path.AddString(message, adjustedMessageFont.FontFamily, (int) fontStyle, (graphics.DpiY * adjustedMessageFont.Size) / 72, Point.Empty, stringFormat);
                            RectangleF graphicsPathBounds = path.GetBounds();
                            PointF[] targetPoints = { new PointF(0, 0), new PointF(ClientSize.Width, 0), new PointF(0, ClientSize.Height) };
                            var translate = new Matrix(graphicsPathBounds, targetPoints);
                            path.Transform(translate);
                            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                            graphics.FillPath(Brushes.LawnGreen, path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
private Font GetAdjustedFont(Graphics graphicRef, string graphicString, Font originalFont, RectangleF container, int maxFontSize, int minFontSize)
    {
        Font testFont = null;
        // We utilize MeasureString which we get via a control instance           
        for (int adjustedSize = maxFontSize; adjustedSize >= minFontSize; adjustedSize--)
        {
            testFont = new Font(originalFont.Name, adjustedSize, originalFont.Style);

            // Test the string with the new size
            SizeF adjustedSizeNew = graphicRef.MeasureString(graphicString, testFont);

            if (container.Width > Convert.ToInt32(adjustedSizeNew.Width) && container.Height > Convert.ToInt32(adjustedSizeNew.Height))
            {
                // Good font, return it
                return testFont;
            }
        }
        return testFont;
    }
```

[The result is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yLrW.png)

After the graphics.FillPath in the above code I try to use the `GraphicsPath` path with the `IsVisible` method to detect if any of the black squares intersect with the drawn text, but the results I get from that have the text in a completely different location than the above result in the image. I can't figure out where the difference, or stretch is coming from.

[path.IsVisible result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZDWX.png)

Comment: Unless your form is borderless and always positioned at 0,0, your measurements are off.  Use the ClientRectangle value of your drawing container.  Don't use CreateGraphics, but use the paint event of the container instead.

Comment: The targetPoints are wrong.  Should be (0, 0), (ClientSize.Width, 0) and (0, ClientSize.Height)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was using `CreateGraphics` because the drawn text was only meant to be temporary and the drawing of the grid and the yellow text in the grid as seen in the second image are created in the paint event of the container. I edited the question above to change the `targetPoints`, which fixed the original alignment issue. I still can't figure out why there is a vertical stretch when using `path.IsVisible` with points from the rectangle grid.

Comment: You are leaking GDI objects here. You need to dispose the "bad" fonts in your GetAdjustedFont loop